# Enforcing coding style with pre-receive Git hook

Tags: c, git, coding-style

I am working on an embedded Linux project with a small team, and we have decided to enforce a C coding style. We have chosen the [Linux Kernel coding style](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst), and we use the script provided in the Kernel tree [checkpatch.pl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/checkpatch.pl) to check our patches.

We would like to check the coding style before accepting a patch on the server, using a pre-receive hook. However, we cannot find a reliable script that does this job, **specially when branches are created and deleted**.

May we solve this problem via Git remote hooks? Specifically, we need to check all the modified files by a commit (or series of commit) with checkpatch.pl.

Comment: Didn’t you like the given answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/caniszczyk/1327469) an example of detection of branches being deleted or created

```
case "$refname" in
  refs/heads/*)
    branch=$(expr "$refname" : "refs/heads/\(.*\)")
      if [ 0 -ne $(expr "$newrev" : "0*$") ]; then # deleting
      ...
      else #updating
        if [ 0 -ne $(expr "$oldrev" : "0*$") ]; then # pushing a new branch
```

You should be to adapt that in order to manage your coding style check.